# Windows not staying maximized when dragged to other monitors

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

If I have an application like Discord or Slack that is maximized, and I drag it to another monitor, it will not be maximized anymore. There will be a gap at the top of the screen and I will have to re-minimize and re-maximize the window to fix it.

Both displays have a resolution of `1920x1080` (which is shown in the Display Settings window) and they are properly aligned.

How can I fix this?

I'm running Windows 10 version 1803

Answer (score 1):

If you turn off
[Arrange windows automatically by dragging them to the sides or corners of the screen](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4343-turn-off-aero-snap-windows-10-a.html)
(Aero Snap), you will also no longer be able to drag maximized windows.

To enable dragging maximized windows, start `regedit`, navigate to
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`
and set the `DragFromMaximize` DWORD to `1` to enable.
Reset to `0` to disable.

For more information see the article
[Enable or Disable Maximized Window Dragging in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4343-turn-off-aero-snap-windows-10-a.html).